# How to write the W under argmin?

Tags: math-mode

I need to write this equation

[image]

See that below **argmin** there is a **w**, I am not getting how to write like that. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}` in the preamble and `\argmin_{w}` in the formula.

Comment: it is not working, it is just attaching  w like this operator $x_n$ at the end of argmin.

Comment: `\bm{w}_{\mathrm{opt}}=\argmin_{\bm{w}}\sum_{n=1]^N\lvert y_n-\bm{w}^T\bm{x}_n\rvert+\lambda\lVert\bm{w}\rVert_{1}` (needs `\usepackage{bm}` after `\usepackage{amsmath}` will produce the required formula. Provided it is used in a display; in inline formulas the subscript will rightly be set next the operator.